# arguments for proc in TCL

Tags: tcl

Is there a way  to pass arguments of a proc from command line? I have my proc in a script. I would like to give its arguments from command line. Is there any equivalent command like "$@" in shell scripting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get command line arguments using these predefined variables.

```
$argc - number items of arguments passed to a script.
$argv - list of the arguments.
$argv0 - name of the script.
```

Answer (score 4):

There are many parts of command line arguments:

- `$argv` — a Tcl list of “useful” argument words. Excludes the name of the script.
- `$argc` — the number of “useful” argument words (i.e., the length of `$argv`); very rarely used given that `[llength $argv]` works just as well.
- `$argv0` — The name of main script being executed.
- `[info nameofexecutable]` — The program that is executing the script. Often called `tclsh` or `wish` (or some variation on that with version numbers and an extension) but definitely not necessarily so.

The simplest way of passing all “useful” argument words — all the words that you'd normally think of as being arguments — to a procedure is to do this (assuming Tcl 8.5 or later):

```
theProc {*}$argv
```

Note that this must come *after* all calls to `proc` are done; `proc` is a command that defines a procedure, not a declaration of a procedure. (The difference? Declarations could conceivably be seen further up the file, but Tcl doesn't work like that.)

I often like to wrap the above in a bit of exception handling in production code so that any errors can be reported nicely instead of dumping a stack trace:

```
if {[catch {theProc {*}$argv} msg]} {
    handleError $msg
}
```

---

Prior to 8.5, you needed a more ugly way:

```
eval theProc $argv
```

This is still safe (in a formal sense) because of how Tcl guarantees to construct list values, and the fact that we know `$argv` to be a proper list.

Answer (score 0):

There is also `args` for variable number of arguments.

```
proc foo args {
    foreach arg $args {
        puts "arg=$arg"
    }
}
```

so calling foo will print this:

```
% foo 1
arg=1
% foo 1 2 3
arg=1
arg=2
arg=3
%
```

Please note that calling this proc with $argv will treat entire content of $argv as a single element in $argc list:

```
$ cat ar.tcl
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
proc foo args {
    foreach arg $args {
        puts "arg=$arg"
    }
}

foo $argv
$ 
$ ./ar.tcl 1 2 3
arg=1 2 3
```

you will need to use `[lindex $args 0]` to get the real `$argv`